# Как перезапустить mongoDB в случае перезагрузки сервера?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mongodb

При перезагрузке ubuntu 18.4 нужно вручную перезапускать mongoDB. Как можно автоматизировать данный процесс?

Comment: нужно выяснить и устранить причину, по которой «нужно перезапускать»

Answer (score 2):

Для автоматического запуска после запуска системы:

```
sudo systemctl enable mongodb
```

Comment: Unit file mongodb.service does not exist.

А что должно быть в этом файле?

Comment: Попробуйте вот так:
update-rc.d mongodb defaults
Про systemd, можно почитать вот тут: 
https://linuxoid.pro/autostart-using-systemd/

Comment: @DmitryFilippov mongod.service в некоторых дистрах